# What does the ValueError : could not broadcast from input array(1) to input array(2) mean?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
while(1):
    img=cv2.imread('D:\IMG_0590_1.jpg')    
    ball = img[278:104, 330:158]
    img[181:355, 100:274] = ball

    cv2.imshow('img',img)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my code but it is giving the above mentioned error. What is the problem?

Comment: After `ball = img[278:104, 330:158]`, `ball` is empty because the first index is bigger then the last. If you meant to flip the matrix left to right, you would like to use step `-1`, like this: `ball = img[278:104:-1, ...]`. do the same for the second index and don't forget the length should be the same when you put it back into the `img` (274-100=174, 330-158=172)

Comment: No i don't want to flip the image. I want to cut a part of an image and place it at some other location. Also can u please tell me whether it is[x1:y1, x2:y2] or [x1:x2 , y1:y2] ?

Comment: `[x1:x2 , y1:y2]`, and `x2` should be larger than `x1`. Also if you do `ball = img[x1:x2, y1:y2]`, and `img[x3:x4, y3:y4] = ball`, then x4-x3 should be equal to x2-x1 and also for the y indices.

Answer (score 0):

the first number in the slice needs to be smaller than the second.
turn

```
ball = img[278:104, 330:158]
```

into

```
ball = img[104:278, 158:330]
```

Also your dimensions don't match.
Ball is 172 pixels wide, and you're putting into a slice 174 pixels wide